# Create new column in data.frames within a list and populate it with specific repeating values

Tags: r, list, lapply, cbind

Here an example of my list (I actually have > 2,000 df in the real one):

```
df1 = read.table(text = 'a b
1 66
1 999
23 89', header = TRUE)

df2 = read.table(text = 'a b
99 61
32 99
83 19', header = TRUE)

lst = list(df1, df2)
```

I need to create a new column for each data.frame within the list and populate each column with a specific number.

```
numbers = c(100, 200)
```

so my output should be:

```
> lst
[[1]]
   a   b  new_col
1  1  66   100
2  1 999   100
3 23  89   100

[[2]]
   a  b  new_col
1 99 61   200
2 32 99   200
3 83 19   200
```

With `lapply` I was able to create a new blank column for each data.frame:

```
lst = lapply(lst, cbind, new_col = '')

> lst
[[1]]
   a   b new_col
1  1  66        
2  1 999        
3 23  89        

[[2]]
   a  b new_col
1 99 61        
2 32 99        
3 83 19
```

But I don't know how to populate the columns with my vector of numbers.

Thanks

Comment: Please ask a new question with your reproducible list and vector instead of updating this one.  Editing this one might invalidate the correct answer.

Comment: Hi the new list is basically the same as the old one.why I get this error?

Comment: Can't say because it works fine with the current data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to iterate both the list of data.frames and vector of numbers at the same time, use `Map()`. For example

```
Map(cbind, lst, new_col=numbers)
# [[1]]
#    a   b new_col
# 1  1  66     100
# 2  1 999     100
# 3 23  89     100
# 
# [[2]]
#    a  b new_col
# 1 99 61     200
# 2 32 99     200
# 3 83 19     200
```